# Handling routes without hashbang using angular-ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've searched a lot online for an answer to this but haven't found anything yet.

Right now I have this code in my file that I thought would handle all routes/states besides the ones I've specified:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

However, this functionality only works for paths like `localhost:1337/#/stuff`, but if I type in `localhost:1337/stuff`, I get an ugly internal server error.

Ideally, I'd like `localhost:1337/stuff` or any other URL without a hashbang to redirect to `localhost:1337/#/` (my app's homepage).

Any thoughts on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set up two things:

1. A so-called "**html5Mode**" in your AngularJS configuration. That's the easy part: `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`
2. Set rewrites on your server so any request renders only your main html page.

From AngularJS [docs on routing](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#server-side):

> Using this mode requires URL rewriting on server side, basically you have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your application (e.g. index.html).

Comment: Thanks for answering! I guess it might be out of scope for my project then.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable html5 mode within your app.js, which will also remove the hashbang from your links in your project (`localhost:1337/stuff` instead of `localhost:1337/#/stuff`).

If this is not the behavior you want, then you'll have to do the rewrites on the server side.